# Function accepting ndarray and float at the same time

Tags: arrays, generics, rust

I would like to write a function computing the refractive index of some material as a function of wavelength. I use the `ndarray` crate for arrays, similar to numpy in Python.
At the moment the function is implemented the following way:

```
fn calc_refractive_index(l: &Array1<f64>) -> Array1<f64> {
    fn refractive_index(&self, l: &Array1<f64>) -> Array1<f64> {
        let V =
            self.A[0] + self.A[1] / (1. + self.A[2] * (self.A[3] * l / self.pitch).mapv(f64::exp));
        let W =
            self.B[0] + self.B[1] / (1. + self.B[2] * (self.B[3] * l / self.pitch).mapv(f64::exp));
        (self.material.refractive_index(&l).powi(2)
            - 3. * l.powi(2) / 4. / (consts::PI * self.pitch).powi(2) * (V.powi(2) - W.powi(2)))
            .mapv(f64::sqrt)
    }
}
```

With the following trait implemented, to make potentiation shorter:

```
trait Squared<T> {
    fn powi(&self, e: i32) -> T;
}

impl Squared<Array1<f64>> for Array1<f64> {
    fn powi(&self, e: i32) -> Array1<f64> {
        self.mapv(|a| a.powi(e))
    }
}
```

However, I may also want to compute the refractive index at only one specific wavelength, so I would like to also accept float64 values. What is the best way to implement this, without implementing two separate functions?

Edit:
The function is using ndarray's syntax for squaring: `l.mapv(|x| x.powi(2))`, which is unfortunately different than for float64

Edit 2:
As asked I included the function body.

Comment: Can you update your answer to show implementations of both versions of the function? Also, is it a hard requirement that a single function handles both of these cases or are you just curious to see if it's possible?

Comment: @pretzelhammer: My question now includes the function body. It is no hard requirement that a single function handles both cases, it's just curiosity as I'm trying to get more familiar with rust, and see what's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible, although it might take more work than simply adding another function. You will need to first define two helper traits that specify the `mapv` and `powi` (much like `Squared`) operations for both `f64` and `Array1<f64>`:

```
trait PowI {
    fn powi(&self, e: i32) -> Self;
}

impl PowI for f64 {
    fn powi(&self, e: i32) -> Self {
        f64::powi(*self, e)
    }
}

impl PowI for Array1<f64> {
    fn powi(&self, e: i32) -> Self {
        self.mapv(|a| a.powi(e))
    }
}

trait MapV {
    fn mapv(&self, f: impl FnMut(f64) -> f64) -> Self;
}

impl MapV for f64 {
    fn mapv(&self, mut f: impl FnMut(f64) -> f64) -> Self {
        f(*self)
    }
}

impl MapV for Array1<f64> {
    fn mapv(&self, f: impl FnMut(f64) -> f64) -> Self {
        Array1::mapv(self, f)
    }
}
```

You can then make your refractive index calculation function be generic over a type `T` that implements both these traits (i.e. `T: PowI + MapV`).

Note that you will also need additional bounds on `T` that specify that it can be added, divided and multiplied with `T`s and `f64`s (which I assume is the type of `self.pitch` and the elements in the `self.A` and `self.B` arrays). You can do this by requiring that `T`, `&'a T` or even `f64` implement the appropriate `Add`, `Mul` and `Div` traits. For example, your implementation may require that `f64: Mul<&'a T, Output=T>` and `T: Div<f64, Output=T>` in addition to many other bounds. The compiler errors will help you figure out exactly which ones you need.

Comment: While this will probably solve my problem, I noticed that using the implemented trait instead of directly using `.mapv(|x| x.powi(e))` caused the execution time to increase by almost 30%, so I now abandoned the idea for the moment